# How to make a .desktop shortcut to a url using firefox

Tags: command-line, firefox, google-chrome, desktop-apps

This is the code I currently use to make a shortcut for a url

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Name=PomoDoneApp
GenericName=PomoDoneApp
Comment=PomoDoneApp desktop webapp
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --app=https://app.pomodoneapp.com/?_ga=2.78761235.644758067.1592449913-2065833867.1590831037#/dashboard
Terminal=false
Icon= /usr/share/icons/pomodoneapp.png
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=text/plain;
Categories=Utility;Application;
Keywords=PomoDoneApp;
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=pomodoneapp
StartupWMClass=app.pomodoneapp.com
```

I want to make the same using firefox cause I don't use chrome, I tried making one with firefox but it doesn't give you full screen and displays add new tab option I replaced Exec with
`/usr/bin/firefox --new-window http://www.cyberciti.biz/`
I need something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9miPa.png) not [result of firefox exec replacing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NNF8.png)

Comment: Simple possible way - by dragging URL from address-bar to desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox is not fully ready with web apps yet, but an experimental feature is available. Give the following a shot.

- Go to about:config and search for browser.ssb.enabled
- Set it true
- Underneath, there is an option browser.ssb with a + button at the right edge. Click that button and a new preference (boolean) will be created, which should also be set true.

Now try the following in your `Exec=` line

```
Exec=firefox --ssb https://app.pomodoneapp.com/?_ga=2.78761235.644758067.1592449913-2065833867.1590831037#/dashboard
```

Comment: It was solved thank you.